# Trying to find the title for a black and white horror film with stage props coming to life

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I'm trying to find the title of this movie from my childhood.

Only scene I remember is that there is a theater and people are enjoying their show, which oddly enough features a big sized cardboard octopus that seems to run on automation gears on stage, that depict a scene from the sea like a storm or something. Kind of like how those shooting gallery duck moves on a flat screen in some fun fair.

I remember that the waves were moving like that. Somehow, the octopus came to life, and with its tentacles, started to drag a few of the victims from the audience seat, and when they were dragged on stage, the victims themselves became cardboard cutouts of the scene.

People start to panic and run for their lives but more horrific things happen as more people get dragged on stage. The story is trying to depict that when things get dragged on stage they became cardboard cutouts in the scene.

I think this is somewhere between 1920s till 1930s

It is most definitely from the U.S. I don't have any idea about actors - just the short plot that I remembered, as this was during the CRT era for television. I could barely make out the actor's faces, at all.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Wow, the 20's was a time when movies were also making their transition from silent movies to movies with sound ... did this movie have sound, or was it silent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the *scene* took place in the 20s or 30s? Because what you're describing is from [High Spirits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095304/combined), which is from 1988. And while the ghosts there might be old, and the stage show is a bit old-timey, the plot *also* takes place in present day. It's also not in black and white.

> When Peter Plunkett's Irish castle turned hotel is about to be repossesed, he decides to spice up the attraction a bit for the 'Yanks' by having his staff pretend to haunt the castle. The trouble begins when a busload of American tourists arrive - along with some real ghosts.

Somewhere after the hour mark, a stage show with paper waves and a fake octopus becomes real, and while a real storm engulfs the people in the room, **the octopus grabs a boy which then turns into a cardboard cutout himself.** The crowd then tosses a lifesaver at him and they pull him out.

See if the trailer rings any bells:

Comment: This is the closest answer to what i remember from back then. Have to watch the movie again to be sure. Cheap crt monitors that only plays in black and white back then might have skewed the timing a bit for me.

Comment: @GuysonOoiKhyeSam Well, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTf25FJdGYI&t=4387s) might help... :)